# How can one test if a tuple is infinite or finite

Tags: typescript

How can one test if a tuple is finite or infinite?

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work for the last case:

```js
type IsFinite<T extends any[], Finite = true, Infinite = false> = T extends []
  ? Finite
  : T extends (infer Element)[]
  ? Element[] extends T
    ? Infinite
    : T extends [any, ...infer Rest]
    ? IsFinite<Rest, Finite, Infinite>
    : never
  : never

 type Foo1 = IsFinite<[string]>                          // true
 type Foo2 = IsFinite<[]>                                // true
 type Foo3 = IsFinite<string[]>                          // false
 type Foo4 = IsFinite<[arg1: string, ...args: string[]]> // false

 type Foo5 = IsFinite<[string, ...[string, number], ...string[], string]> // never <- doesn't handle this case
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=111&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgMQJYDsnAgHgCpQgDwxQBM4oBDFEAbQF0AaKZNDKAXimACcBXCRmCgBmqdNA5DyAGzgQAfOyi4CRUlDoAoKFAD8TURi1QAXEryEIJMgApUQiFygBRKRAC2l4AEpN2vS-dPOnNVMmwjP1hhAwgIkzMVSzVqShBGADpMuwcoACUIOGBaOL14ZjFMfMLGcowBaJZ5ONMUCAA3ByMW9s6tUEgmAHtBgEZFMpjMakKuVABzWgVtZZXVtdWAeg3OXljOcGgEYYAmccRJuiX165u1rZ2+PoOhwYBmM9qsGfnL27-N7aSGR7fqHYYAFg+F3IXDmI1M3xQcwymRhczgCO4P1oiyg9yBsg0TwGR0GAFYoY0pojkVBMulplikYwUDw3AAjBwMOmZGl0Rg03H3VodRyYAC0UGIgwKKAA5MAoAALSjEVycJVIMgAY3IsiAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1nEGN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by an "infinite" array/[tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) you mean an array type without a known upper bound on its `length`; and in TypeScript that would mean an array type whose `length` property is `number`, as opposed to a "finite" array/tuple whose `length` property is some numeric [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) or [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of such literals:

```
type Length<T extends any[]> = T['length'];

type L1 = Length<[string]>                          // 1
type L2 = Length<[]>                                // 0
type L3 = Length<string[]>                          // number
type L4 = Length<[arg1: string, ...args: string[]]> // number
type L5 = Length<[string, ...[string, number], ...string[], string]> // number
type L6 = Length<[string, string?]> //  1 | 2
```

So you can define `IsFinite<T>` as a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that checks the type of the `length` property:

```
type IsFinite<T extends any[], F = true, I = false> =
    number extends T['length'] ? I : F

type Foo1 = IsFinite<[string]>                          // true
type Foo2 = IsFinite<[]>                                // true
type Foo3 = IsFinite<string[]>                          // false
type Foo4 = IsFinite<[arg1: string, ...args: string[]]> // false
type Foo5 = IsFinite<[string, ...[string, number], ...string[], string]> // false
type Foo6 = IsFinite<[string, string?]> //  true
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)